# Algorithm:Sort using Median and Just 1 comparison in $ O(n \log n) $

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to write an sorting algorithm which takes an input array and produces the sorted array. Following are the constraints for an algorithm.

1. Time complexity = $O(n \log n)$
2. Only one comparison operation throughout the algorithm.
3. We have a function which can provide an median for a set of three elements.

I have tried finding a solution and following is my result.

1. we use the median function to get the smallest and the largest pair. 
   Example: Give an array A[1..n], we get the median of the first three elements, lets call it a set and we receive a $Median$. In next Iteration we remove the received median from the set and add next element to the set and again call Median function. This step when repeated over the length produces a pair of the largest and the smallest element for the entire array.
2. We use this pair, use the comparison operation and place them at position A[0] & A[n-1].
3. We repeat the same operation over the array A[1..n-2] to get another pair of the largest and smallest.
4. We take the median with the A[0] and newly received pair.
5. Median Value is placed at the A[1].
6. We take the median with the A[n-1] and newly received pair.
7. Median Value is placed at the A[n-2].

Step 3~7 are repeated to get a sorted array.

This algorithm satisfies the condition 2 & 3 but not the time complexity. I hope if someone can provide some guidance how to proceed further.

Comment: Only one comparison operation throughout the algorithm (can you claify this)? That doesn't seem possible if you have a median operation (which requires a comparison) as well as the actual sort function (which will also require a comparison). Overall sounds like an implementation of `quicksort` or `mergesort`. Also: `3.We repeat the same operation over the array A[1..n-2]`. That seems like an odd subset - why cut off just the outside values if you want `O(n ln n)` time? Don't you want to half the array?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. One comparison in addition to the one's done by the Median Function. In the context of the current problem, we consider Median function as an unit and don't consider the time or operation done by it i.e MedianFunction takes \theta(1).

Comment: That sooouunnddss like `quicksort`, although that's usually done with two comparisons (I believe the same is true for `mergesort` as well). Since it's `n-lg(n)`, you must be halving the side of the array with each recursion, but in order to know when to stop, you need at least one comparison (indicating there's only one element in the array). Then you need another comparison within the actual sort-loop itself. That's at least two right there...

Comment: Offhand, I think I could write `quicksort` with about 5 or so comparisons (without some insane creativity)... you might be able to do `mergesort` with a couple fewer, but doing it with *one* seems impossible. You may want to ask for clarification. You can probably do an `insertion`/`bubble`/`selection` style sort with one comparison, but then, that's obviously not `nlg(n)` time

Comment: I am not aware of the Quick sort, but in case of the merge sort, we have more than 1 comparison at each recursion. Thus having least \log n comparison. This violates the constraint i.e. to have just one comparison in the entire execution of the algorithm.

Comment: The challenge here is that `nlg(n)` time seems to imply a recursive algorithm. But you would *have* to have at least one comparison to determine when to stop recursing (you follow me?). Unless by comparison they just mean within the sort itself. Even so, if there were an algorithm that allowed you to get `nlg(n)` time with just one comparison, I think people would be using that all the time since that's *way* less work than `quick`/`merge` sort. I think you may wish to ask for clarification.

Comment: Also, I'll write up a quick example of `quicksort` so you have it on file for furture reference.

Comment: Yes, I do follow. I have been trying to figure out the way for the same but no luck. I will take your suggestion and ask for the clarification and continue based upon the feedback received.  Just to make sure, my algorithm's run time can be given by \theta (n^2).

Comment: "I am not aware of the Quick sort" : and still you post a tricky question about algorithm and dare using O() notation !! -->> let's this close this homework question, SO is not about helping students to cheat.

Comment: Nothing wrong with homework questions. They can be helpful to the community as well. As long as there is some effort put forth by the OP (which I'm convinced there is).

Comment: @axrwkr: I have not written any code but i have tried to come-up with an algorithm. I didn't write any code as I wasn't convinced that algorithm devised my me satisfies all the constraints.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: I am not seeking any ready made solutions. I have put sincere effort to come up with a solution and I did come-up with one. I found the drawbacks of my original solution and when I ran out of ideas, I tried to ask the community. I hope you could guide me further as I have hit a wall.

Comment: @sircodesalot quicksort is not O(n*log(n)). Big O notation is about worst case complexity, quicksort has worst case complexity of n squared. Its average complexity is n * log(n) and it gets its name from the fact that it use locality well which means in real applications, it tends to run faster than O(n*log(n)) sorts, but this is clearly a very theoretical question.

Comment: @user1612868 `Big O notation is about worst case complexity`. Expressing an upper bound is noooot quite the same thing as expressing worst case. For example, while quicksort *is* quadratic worst case (as you mentioned), O-notation is not the same thing as stating 'best/average/worst'. For example, if we want to say that `quicksort` has average case nlog(n), it's not correct to state that it's Theta-nlog(n), because theta implies O and Omega. We just instead state that it's *average case* `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: @sircodesalot [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). Theta is O and Omega. Omega is short hand for best case. O is short hand for worst case. The reason that it is incorrect to call it Theta(n * log(n)) is because it is not O. (It is Omega.) But for all n0, k there exists some n > n0 and some list L such that len(L) = n and quicksort(L) runs in greater than k * log(n) time. Hence, the standard definition of big O is not satisfied.

Comment: (continued) Adding in "average case" corrects the problem because it becomes clear that you are talking about the average over the set of all lists of length n rather than individual lists of length n. And the worst average for any sufficiently large length n is better than n * log(n). However, the word average did not occur in the question or in your discussion with the OP.

Comment: @user1612868 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: [Solution]: I tried and with the help of @tmyklebu, I was finally come-up with a solution where all the condition are satisfied. In order to do it, we need to write an comparison function using the oracle and then use heap sort to sort the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort (presented in reverse order) works like this. Suppose you have an array:

```
 [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Quicksort in the abstract basically works by sliding towards the middle of the array from both the left and the right side. As we slide inwards, we want to swap items such that big things get moved to the right, and small things get moved to the left. Eventually we should have an array where all the small stuff is on the left, and all the big stuff is on the right.

The upshot of this process *also* guarantees that one element will be placed in the correct location (because everything to the left of it will be smaller, and everything to the right will be bigger, so it *must* be in the right position). That value is called the `pivot`. The first step of quicksort is to ensure the pivot is in the right place.

The way we do this is by selecting a random element to be our `pivot` - the item we wan to put into it's correct place. For this simple example we'll just use the last number `(3)`. The `pivot` is our comparison value.

Once we have selected our `pivot`/comparison value, we then monitor the left-most element `(1)`, and the right-most element `(3)`. We'll call these the `left-pointer` and the `right-pointer`. The `left-pointers` job is to slide towards the middle of the array, stopping when it finds something that is larger than the `pivot`. The `right` pointer does the same thing, but it slides inward looking for values *less* than the `pivot`. In code:

```
while (true) {
    while (array[++left] < pivot);
    while (array[--right] > pivot) if (left == right) break;

    if (left >= right) break;           // If the pointers meet then exit the loop
    swap(array[left], array[right]);    // Swap the values otherwise.
}
```

So in our example above, when the `left-pointer` hits `(4)` it recognizes that that is higher than our pivot element and stops moving. The right pivot does the same thing from the right side, but stops when it hits `(2)` because that's *lower* than the `pivot`. When both sides stop, we do a swap, so we end up with:

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

Notice that we are getting closer to sorted. We continue to move both pointers inward until they both point to the same element, or they cross - whichever comes first. When that happens, we make one final step, which is to replace the pivot element `(3)` with whatever point the `left/right-pointers` are pointing to, which in this case would be `(5)` because they would both stop right in the middle. Then we swap, so that we get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
(Notice that we swap the original pivot (3) with the value pointed to by both sides (5))
```

This whole process is called a **partition**. In code it looks like this:

```
int partition(int *array, int lBound, int rBound) {
    int pivot = array[rBound];          // Use the last element as a pivot
    int left = lBound - 1;              // Point to one before the first element
    int right = rBound;             // Point to the last element;

    // We'll break out of the loop explicity
    while (true) {

        while (array[++left] < pivot);
        while (array[--right] > pivot) if (left == right) break;

        if (left >= right) break;    // If the pointers meet then exit the loop
        swap(array[left], array[right]);    // Swap the pointers otherwise.
    }

    swap(array[left], array[rBound]);   // Move the pivot item into its correct place
    return left;    // The left element is now in the right place
}
```

It's important to note that although the partition step fully sorted our array in this example, *that's not ordinarily the point of the partition step*. The point of the paritition step is to put *one* element into it's correct place, and to ensure that everything left of that element is *less* and everything to the right is *more*. Or in other words, to move the `pivot` value into its correct location and then guarantee that everything left of the pivot is smaller than it, and everything to the right is bigger. So although in this example the array was completely sorted, in general we can only guarantee that *one* item and *one* item only is in the correct location (and everything to the left and right is bigger/smaller respectively). This is why the `partition` method above returns `left`, because it tells the calling function that this *one* element is in the correct location (and the array has been correctly partitioned).

That is if we start with an array like:

```
[1, 7, 5, 4, 2, 9, 3]
```

Then the partition step would return something like this:

```
[1, 3, 2, [4], 7, 5, 9]
```

Where [4] is the only value guaranteed to be in the right place, but everything to the left is smaller than [4] and everything to the right is *bigger* (though *not* necessarily sorted!).

The second step is to perform this step recursively. That is, if we can put one element into it's correct location, then we should be able to eventually put all items into their correct location. That is the `quicksort` function. In code:

```
int *quicksort(int *array, int lBound, int rBound) {
    if (lBound >= rBound) return array;   // If the array is size 1 or less - return.

    int pivot = partition(array, lBound, rBound);   // Split the array in two. 
    quicksort(array, lBound, pivot - 1);    // Sort the left size. (Recursive)
    quicksort(array, pivot + 1, rBound);    // Sort the right side. (Recursive) 

    return array;
}
```

Notice that the first step is to ensure that we have an array side of at least 2. It doesn't make sense to process anything smaller than that so we return if that condition isn't met. The next step is to call our partition function which will split the array according to the process outlined above. Once we know that the array has one element that is in correct position, we simply call quicksort again, but this time on the left side of the pivot, and then again on the right side of the pivot. *Notice we don't include the pivot because the partition is guaranteed to put that into the correct location!*

If we continue to call `quicksort` recursively, eventually we'll halve the array and partition it until we get arrays of size-one (which by definition is already sorted). So we partition, then halve, partition, halve, etc. until the entire array is sorted (in place). This gives us a sort in `O(n lg(n))` time. Cool!

Here's a quick example of it's use:

```
int main() {
    int array [] {1, 0, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6};

    quicksort(array, 0, 9); // Sort from zero to 9.

    // Display the results
    for (int index = 0; index != 10; ++index) {
        cout << array[index] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A good visual demonstration can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5nSXTnD1I4

Comment: No I get that, we had a discussion about this before. But the OP was unaware of what quicksort is, so I wrote one up. See conversation above.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 1 and 2 are indeed the first steps of a correct solution.  Once you know the smallest and largest elements, though, the median oracle *is* a comparison oracle; if you want to compare `a[i]` with `a[j]`, then `a[i] < a[j]` exactly when `a[i] = median(a[i], a[j], a[0])` where `a[0]` is the smallest element.  So you can run straight quicksort or mergesort or whathaveyou.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the point where quicksort or mergesort can be used once I have the known values for the largest and the smallest element.

Comment: @Mattlee: They're comparison-based sorts.  I just told you how to do comparisons.  You can take it from there.